# How to reference a unique key of a Firebase Realtime Database object then update a bool value that is stored Locally? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, local-storage

I want to reference a specific object from my Database (Firebase Realtime) and change that specific object's key and change a bool value of that specific object (using; the key)...but the bool value is stored locally so it is hard to reference the database and the locally stored bool. Here is a picture to understand beter: [Representaion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA6IO.png)

Here is the unique key given to each object in the database:

```
dataB['key'] = snapshot.value;
//the dataB is the name of the Database so here I'm referencing it
```

And the bool value (joined) code:

```
bool joined = false;
//Extra info: I am storing this bool using Shared Preferences
```

What I want is when I press on a button it should change the bool value to true but it should only change the specific key:

```
onPressed: () {
   isJoined = true;
//when I print what it is referencing here it is referencing 
//EVERYTHING in the database [this is the problem!!]
//How do I reference just one specific key?
}
```

So now I want to change a specific object in the database and give it a default bool value false and when I click on a button it should change the bool value to true and it should store that bool value locally but it should just be that unique object in the database.

What I've tried:
I was thinking of adding a specific id to each object in the database so that I can reference it like that but there is already a unique key given to each object so I ended up not doing it, but if it is better that way please let me know. I don't exactly know how to search this so I can't really check the internet. I also tried asking for ChatGPT but that didn't help.

Comment: If you want to change the value of a specific path in the database, your code will need to know that path (including the `key` you reference), and then you call the API to [write a value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#basic_write) there. To toggle the boolean value, you'll want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions), which allows you to first-read-then-write the value.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short the answer to my problem was not creating a bool value then changing the bool value when you click on a button. The answer and probably the best method was to store a `List<String>` (A list so that I can work with each individual item in the Database). So I ended up using Shared Preferences to store a List so that I can work with more than just a single item in the database.

Here is the Shared Preferences documentation if you need more information on Shared Preferences: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/key-value

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).